Plethora of bogus errors in Xcode/Swift
I have a large Swift project that I'm writing in Xcode. It compiles & runs fine.
Starting yesterday, I've been seeing a huge number of bogus errors showing up, hundreds of them all at once. Things like
Cannot find 'xxxxx' in scope

where xxxxx is something that's declared in the project, like funcs and structs and enums.
At first I thought I'd unbalanced a delimiter, like an extra or missing ) or }. Or that a module had been somehow deleted from the project. But that's not the case -- all the declarations are right where they've always been.
And, when I click ▶️, the project still build & runs just fine, even with these hundreds of errors highlighting lines red and the red " 957" notation on the top of the window!  So, clearly, part of Xcode, the part that actually compiles things, knows that the code is fine.  But the part that highlights errors, not so much.
Things I've tried:

Product > Clear All Issues: this does remove the errors for a time, but they come back.
Product > Clean Build Folder: sometimes this removes the errors, sometimes it doesn't.  But they do come back.
Cleaning Build Folder, then quitting Xcode, then starting it again, and Cleaning the Build Folder immediately: also can remove the errors for a while, but they keep coming back.

Sometimes I get a small number (like 5 to 10) of errors highlighted (the usual 'cannot find xxxxx', maybe just one xxxxx in one file that's "missing"); other times the count is in the hundreds, and not always the same number. In fact, when I switch to another file, more lines get highlighted & the count goes up.  In every case, the app does build & run. So it isn't a matter of needing to find an error in the code, but rather figuring out what is causing whatever part of Xcode that highlights errors to now regularly lose its mind.
Other notes:

No references to anything external to the project: no pods or similar.
Import statements: Foundation and SwiftUI, plus UIKit (in 2 files). Nothing else.
Total number of files is 104
Don't recall ever seeing this until yesterday. Fairly unremarkable edits & additions being made when the problem started - not adding anything new & cosmic to the project.
Xcode version 15.4, been running fine for weeks, no recent updates.
Sonoma 14.5, also stable for weeks, no recent changes
16 GB ram, 10 GB of 250 GB available on the hard drive.


TLDR: How do I get rid of all these bogus red 'error' highlights, and keep them from coming back?

Try a cleanup by following the steps shown in the answer to Xcode 14.2 not displaying errors despite troubleshooting steps

Quit Xcode. Restart the computer. Without doing anything else, delete the entire contents of this folder:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
Delete this file:
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
Empty the trash. Now open your project in Xcode.

This. Xcode sometimes loses its mind.

That works, although the computer (desktop) seems to be doing this more & more frequently. Disk space is a bit low (11 of 250 GB free); is that enough to cause this condition? Now affecting two moderately large projects, not just the original one.

@ConfusionTowers That sort of question belongs on Ask Different, not Stack Overflow. But 11 GB free out of 250 GB is tragic. You can't even update Xcode at that point.
